# Javascript conditional not working

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

Im struggling with a simple conditional error. Currently, I'm getting two class added simultaneously rather than just one. I need help figuring out why this is happening. I would like to add a class to the span when the value from the slider is between data-min and data-max which can be found in the html.

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.o-donation--slider');
var itemHighlight = document.querySelectorAll('.item--highlight span');
slider.oninput = function() {
  for (var j = itemHighlight.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var dataMin = itemHighlight[j].dataset.min;
    var dataMax = itemHighlight[j].dataset.max;
    if (this.value > dataMin && this.value < dataMax) {
      itemHighlight[j].classList.add('active');
    } else {
      itemHighlight[j].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="col s12 align-center">
    <input class="o-donation--slider" type="range" min="1" max="5000" value="100">
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col s12 align-center item--highlight">
  <span data-min="1" data-max="249">number</span>
  <span data-min="250" data-max="449">number</span>
  <span data-min="500" data-max="999">number</span>
  <span data-min="1000" data-max="2000">number</span>
  <span data-min="2001" data-max="3000">number</span>
  <span data-min="3001" data-max="5000">number</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: When does this code run? Your script can only run correctly after the DOM has already loaded - so if your script runs at the start of the page it won't work . Wrap your code in an event-handler for `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @Mamun That `for` loop looks correct to me. It counts downwards/backwards.

Comment: You should avoid using the `onfoo`-style events and use `addEventListener` instead, so use `slider.addEventListener('input', function... )` instead.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of what is happening. (https://jsfiddle.net/akvsfnoj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the dataset values into numbers first - in your version, you're comparing their *strings*:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.o-donation--slider');
const itemHighlightSpans = document.querySelectorAll('.item--highlight span');
slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const sliderValue = slider.value;
  itemHighlightSpans.forEach(itemHighlightSpan => {
    const { min, max } = itemHighlightSpan.dataset;
    const minNum = Number(min);
    const maxNum = Number(max);
    if (sliderValue >= minNum && sliderValue <= maxNum) itemHighlightSpan.classList.add('active');
    else itemHighlightSpan.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="col s12 align-center">
    <input class="o-donation--slider" type="range" min="1" max="5000" value="100">
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col s12 align-center item--highlight">
  <span data-min="1" data-max="249">number</span>
  <span data-min="250" data-max="449">number</span>
  <span data-min="500" data-max="999">number</span>
  <span data-min="1000" data-max="2000">number</span>
  <span data-min="2001" data-max="3000">number</span>
  <span data-min="3001" data-max="5000">number</span>
</div>
```